# What is wrong with following Javascript statement?

Tags: javascript

The following code gives error.

```
var user;

user.load= function () {

//

}
```

It gives error `Cannot read property 'load' of undefined`

EDIT: Isn't everything an Object by default in Javascript?

Comment: what is the question? `user` is `undefined`; you cannot assign into it.

Comment: The error message should be `Cannot set a property ("load") on undefined`

Comment: undefined variables are `undefined`, not `{}`

Comment: *"Isn't everything an Object by default in Javascript?"* No. Every value but a *primitive* value is an object. `undefined` (the default value of initialized variables) is a primitive value and doesn't have an object equivalent (like strings for example), so autoboxing  doesn't take place.

Comment: @Swagg, everything is an object, but that variable doesn't hold anything.  It's undefined.  `var user = 1;  user.load = function(){}` would work (you just wouldn't be able to access it later... it's complicated).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Primitive values are not objects.

Comment: @FelixKling, yeah you're right.  But then why is this valid?  `Number.prototype.load = function(){ alert("this works");}; (1).load();` Isn't it an object if it has a prototype?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Because the value is [autoboxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoboxing#Autoboxing). See also http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1. If you have a property reference (which `(1).load` is), then the value is first converted to an object by calling `ToObject` before the reference is resolved.

Comment: So, number 1 is not an object, but in  var d =1; d is an object, right?

Comment: @Swagg: No, it's still a primitive value. Assigning a primitive value to a variable does not convert it to an object. Only accessing a property  converts it *temporarily* to an object. That's why `var foo = 42; foo.bar = 'hey!'; alert(foo.bar);` shows `undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling. so the `undefined` is the `value` of `foo.bar`, temporarily generated, but not defined, inside the alert statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `user` variable needs to be an object in order for you to assign properties to it. Variables that have not been assigned a value are `undefined`, and you can't assign properties to `undefined`.

```
var user = {};
user.load = function () {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `var user = new Object();`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var user = {};

user.load= function () {

//

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = {};
user.load= function () {

//

}
```

At the moment user is `undefined`, where it needs to be an object.

Comment: It is an object too. But its value is undefined. Which is why you can't tag properties to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = {
   load: function(){
        return 'hi';
   }
};
user.load();
```

or

```
var user = function(){
   this.load = function(){
      return 'Hi';
   }
}
```

Comment: For the second one to work, you have to create an instance of the constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't everything an Object by default in Javascript?

No. Many things are objects, but the default value of a variable is `undefined`, and that is is a primitive which cannot be assigned properties.

You need to assign an object (a new empty object is fine) to the variable:

```
var user = {};
```